# Net force on a particle in rotational motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

I'm confused as to why the net force acting on the first particle looks like the highlighted vector in the 3rd picture.

[image]

It seems to me that the net force vector should look like the red vector in the following picture:

[image]

Is my drawing wrong? If so, where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrows are representative and should not be looked at as exact.  They give you a rough idea as to where forces may develop, but I suspect no one worked it out as a problem and made sure the summation was correct.

Answer (score 2):

The component of $F$ in the direction of $T_1$ must be smaller or equal to it. Otherwise there would be an acceleration in that direction increasing $r_1$, what contradicts the statement of rigid connections. The magnitude of $F$ in the drawing suggests that it is greater than that.

Comment: When you are referring to $F$, do you mean the net force vector? Also, when you say "The magnitude of F in the drawing suggests that it is greater than that." Do you mean my drawing or the textbook's drawing?

Comment: Do you mean that my drawing (purple) is wrong? If so, could you tell me how I could improve it?

Comment: I mean $F$ compared with $T_1$ in the figure 9.8b